# Watir how to click on nested element

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to click on **"Mr"** from the `drop down list` I've tried a combination of things but non of them seem to work.

I've even tried `xpath` which is usually reliable but for this case its failing.

```
$browser.element(:xpath, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/a").click
```

[image: click on MR]

Answer (score 5):

The XPath suggested by Saurabh Gaur, can be written in a more readable Watir-like fashion using:

```
$browser.ul(class: 'dropdown-menu').link(text: 'Mr').click
```

Note that this assumes that there is only one `ul` element with class `dropdown-menu`. If there are multiple, you will need to scope the search to the specific dropdown using an element that likely exists higher in the DOM.

However, given there is likely only one link with text "Mr", you can probably get away with simply:

```
$browser.link(text: 'Mr').click
```

Given the link is a dialog that switches from hidden to visible, you may need to also wait:

```
$browser.link(text: 'Mr').when_present.click
```

Comment: $browser.link(text: 'Mr').when_present.click worked nicely for very clean code as well!!

Answer (score 1):

Your `xPath` is positional which depends on `element` position.. it will not work if `elements` are change their position means adding some `elements` after some action on the page.

After seeing your attached image I have generated following `xPath` as below :-

```
//ul[contains(@class, 'dropdown-menu')]/descendant::span[contains(.,'Mr')]/parent::a
```

Try with this `xPath`.. May be it will work...:)

Comment: Thanks Saurabh that worked perfectly!! is there any documentation I can read about this, I have a few more scenarios where this is going to come in handy

Comment: @JosephKouroma Yeah you can follow these link to understand `xpath syntax` http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp and  for `xpath axes` http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp

Comment: @JosephKouroma please don't forget to accept the answer if it's helpful..:)

Comment: Using xpath with Watir is supported, but should be avoided where possible. Watir is designed to be highly readable, and using xpath negates that value and is almost never necessary.  (Compare the obscure syntax above with Justin's answer).

Comment: @titusfortner...yes Justin's answer is more reliable than me but my answer came and your problem resolved too before justin's answer...so after that everyone can give you better answer..you never know any other answerer can give better answer than Justine..so point is, this is programming and here anyone can give you better than better solution...anyway thanks for this...:)